# How to do this in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I can't express what I want to do. Please help. Considering my code below:

```
void Main()
{
    List<Person> person = new List<Person>
    {
        new Person { Name = "Maria Anders", Age = 21 },
        new Person { Name = "Ana Trujillo", Age = 55 },
        new Person { Name = "Thomas Hardy", Age = 40 },
        new Person { Name = "Laurence Lebihan", Age = 18 },
        new Person { Name = "Victoria Ashworth", Age = 16 },
        new Person { Name = "Ann Devon", Age = 12 }
    };

    person.Select(x => new { x.Name, x.Age }).Dump();
}

class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

I want to print the `Name | Age | Status` of a person.

`Status` is a derived column. Where it should have a value of either "`Adult`" if the person's age is >= 18, otherwise "Under age".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you need to add a property named `Status` to class `Person`.

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Status 
    {
       get { return Age >= 18 ? "Adult" : "Under age"; }
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
       return string.Format("{0}|{1}|{2}",Name,Age,Status);
    }
}
```

then you can loop into the list of person to do your action:

```
foreach(Person p in persons)
{
    Console.WriteLine(p);
}
//Or
persons.ForEach( p => Console.WriteLine(p) );
```

The reason of adding `Status` property and overriding `ToString` method is to put the logic in one place. Otherwise, suppose some day, you need to change "Under age" to "Nonage", you won't need to change the strings everywhere but only one place in your `Person` class.

Comment: `Status` is a derived column not a property.

Comment: @yonan2236: You should make it a property,that's the correct way. Otherwise every time you want to display the `Status`, you need to write this logic(age>=18).

Comment: @yonan: If you tell me you can't change the source code of `Person`, that's another thing.

Comment: @yonan: "derived column" vs "computed property" - what's the difference? Having it in one place is cleaner if you ever reuse this class.

Comment: I don't get it... Why you should make a property if you just can derived it based from the other property of the class?

Comment: @yonan: The property is just syntactic sugar. You're not *storing* that value. Look in the `get` function -- you are calculating it every time it's accessed. It's still computed, it's just in a more convenient place, for the reasons Danny explained in his answer (the justification behind the "don't repeat yourself" principle).

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
person.Select(p =>
  String.Format("{0} | {1} | {2}",
  p.Name, p.Age, p.Age >= 18 ? "Adult" : "Under age"))
  .Dump();
```

Then somewhere else:

```
static void Dump(this IEnumerable<string> ss)
{
    foreach(var s in ss)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
person.Select(x => new { x.Name, x.Age ,Status = (x.Age>=18) ? "Adult":"Under Age"})
```

Answer (score 0):

var y =    person.Select(x => new { x.Name, x.Age, Status = x.Age > 18 ? "Adult" : "Minor" });

Answer (score 0):

Its simple.. sb.ToString() will give you what you want.

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach(Person p in person)
        {
        string status = p.Age >= 18 ? "Adult" : "Not Adult";

        sb.AppendLine(String.Format("{0} {1} {2}",p.Name,p.Age.ToString(),status));
        sb.AppendLine(Environment.NewLine);

        }
```

Comment: the question was about Linq. This is the not the answer he is looking for.

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
person.Select(x => new {Name =  x.Name, Age = x.Age, Status = ((x.Age>=18) ? "Adult" :"Child") }); ;
```